# Function to change dates based on time period?

Tags: python, function

I have a df of id's and dates. What I'd like to do is set the same date for a 2 day time period. Having trouble writing a function for this. Its like using the equivalent to a SQL OVER PARTITION BY

```
Input:
d1 = {'id': ['a','a','a','a','b','a','b'], 'datetime': ['10/25/2021 0:00','10/26/2021 0:00','11/28/2021 0:00','11/29/2021 0:00','11/29/2021 0:00', '11/30/2021 0:00', '11/30/2021 0:00']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime'])

Desired Output:
d3 = {'id': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b'], 'datetime': ['10/25/2021 0:00','10/25/2021 0:00','11/28/2021 0:00','11/28/2021 0:00', '11/30/2021 0:00','11/29/2021 0:00','11/29/2021 0:00']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d3)
```

The solution I'm looking for should group by id sorted by datetime. With the first datetime value in that group, create a group of all rows within a 2 day time period and assign those rows with that first datetime value, then move on to the next date and repeat. Then move on to the next id.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby`:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
output = df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::2].reindex(x.index).ffill()).sort_values(["id", "datetime"])

>>> output

  id   datetime
0  a 2021-10-25
1  a 2021-10-25
2  a 2021-11-28
3  a 2021-11-28
5  a 2021-11-30
4  b 2021-11-29
6  b 2021-11-29
```

Comment: So this checks every 2 rows. I want it to start over for every id. So index 3 should not change based on index 2 because ID for index 3 is b and index 2 is a. How can we change this?

Comment: @chicagobeast12 - Edited. Just FYI, this solution is much faster than looping over the dataframe.

Comment: The problem with this is you're assuming that my 2 day window only means I can have 2 rows in one group ie (10/25, 10/26). It doesn't work if I had (10/25, 10/26, 10/26) in a group. The result with your solution would be (10/25, 10/25, 10/26). If you have a one-liner fix for this... would love to use it, but if not no worries

Comment: What should your result be for 10/25, 10/25, 10/26? I thought you meant you want to fill forward every two rows. This is why you need to explain your question more clearly in the OP and include all such cases.

Comment: I said 2 day time period, not 2 consecutive rows. And in the OP, I clearly stated it should keep evaluating for the same id until that 2 day window ends. I get that its a convoluted solution I'm looking for, but tried to do my best to state the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df1.sort_values(by=['id'])
oldest = {df1.iloc[0,0]: dt.strptime(df1['datetime'][0], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")}
for t in range(df1['datetime'].shape[0]):
    if df1.iloc[t,0] in oldest:
        if ((dt.strptime(df1['datetime'][t],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") - oldest[df1.iloc[t,0]]).days) >1:
            oldest[df1.iloc[t,0]] = dt.strptime(df1['datetime'][t], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    else:
        oldest[df1.iloc[t, 0]] = dt.strptime(df1['datetime'][t], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    df1.iloc[t, 1] = oldest[df1.iloc[t, 0]]
```

The output would be:

```
  id             datetime
0  a  2021-10-25 00:00:00
1  a  2021-10-25 00:00:00
2  a  2021-11-28 00:00:00
3  a  2021-11-28 00:00:00
4  b  2021-11-29 00:00:00
5  a  2021-11-30 00:00:00
6  b  2021-11-29 00:00:00
```

Comment: Does this account for id?

Comment: what do you need about id?

Comment: In your question, your desired output for id, didn't say anything. What is your desired id like?

Comment: When the id changes (ie row 2 to 3), the function should start over. Changed the input/desired output in the question to make it more clear. sorry

Comment: I still cannot get your point. Your desired id is still the same!

Comment: So your solution changes the datetime value for row 4 based on row 3. This change should not happen because the id for row 4 is different than row 3... if that makes sense?

Comment: I get you now. Wait for me to upload your desired answer

Comment: The solution I'm looking for should group by id sorted by datetime. With the first datetime value in that group, create a group of all rows within a 2 day time period and assign those rows with that first datetime value, then move on to the next date and repeat. Then move on to the next id. Very convoluted so I apologise, but hope that makes sense

Comment: can you include more samples in your dataframe inside your question?

Comment: Definitely... was working on that now actually

Comment: Okay check the updated question now. Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: Check my answer. Just don't forget to include your time inside quotations.
If it works for you, please give me an upvote and accept my answer as your desired solution

Comment: d1 = {'id': ['a','a','a','a','b','a','b'], 'datetime': ['10/25/2021 0:00','10/26/2021 0:00','11/28/2021 0:00','11/29/2021 0:00','11/29/2021 0:00', '11/30/2021 0:00', '11/30/2021 0:00']}

Comment: Open to chatting, solution doesn't work... don't see where it evaluates the next 'id' before assigning the new date. Think its really close though